# gRPC C++ build on Windows 10 how?

Tags: c++, windows, build, cmake, grpc

I am having no end of trouble trying to build gRPC on Windows 10 using Visual Studio 2015 (C++) and cmake.

I have downloaded and unzipped grpc from GitHub, along with all its .gitmodules (and their .gitmodules, etc.) and unzipped them to their specified locations.  When I cmake grpc, it complains about no CMakeLists.txt in cares/cares.  grpc's .gitmodules specifies cares-1_12_0, and that includes no CMakeLists.txt file.  What to do?  The master version of cares/cares includes a CMakeLists.txt file, so I copied it into the -1_12_0 tree.  Now it finds CMakeLists.txt, but then complains of other files that it can't find.
If I just use the master version of cares instead of 1_12_0 (hoping whatever incompatibility has been fixed by now), I get no more cares complaints.  Another way that I have found to get past the cares complaints is to unzip c-ares-master.zip into grpc/third_part/cares/cares and then unzip c-ares-cares-1_12_0.zip in the same place.  I figure that that way c-ares-master.zip will provide any files that c-ares-cares-1_12_0.zip is missing, and c-ares-cares-1_12_0.zip will overwrite any files with the same names with the -1_12_0 version -- but is this a good practice (copying a specific branch on top of the master version when a specific version is specified)?  (I am not using git to download because it is not available or approved for use here, so I must traverse the dependencies manually.)

The next complaint is from protobuf 3.0.x: repeated_field_reflection.h not found, but this is only a Warning.

Then there are Errors thrown from benchmark about can't find GTEST_LIBRARY, GTEST_INCLUDE_DIR, and GTEST_MAIN_LIBRARY.

Do I need to build/install all these submodules (from bottom up) before I try to build grpc?  Differences between the different modules' build procedures (and resulting build directory structures) suggest to me that the answer to this question should be 'no', but I am not sure.  I understand that cmake provides support for recursive builds down a source tree (through all third_party dependencies) starting from a single root CMakeLists.txt (i.e., a single execution of cmake should build everything), so it would make sense for this ability of cmake to be used and that dependents' build directory structures should be consistent.

I note that grpc's .gitmodules requires protobuf 3.0.x, but it also lists bloaty, and bloaty's .gitmodules requires protobuf (presumably, the master version).  Will using different versions of protobuf in different parts of the src tree (and building two versions of protobuf) cause problems?  If so, what should I do when different parts of the tree require different versions of the same module?

Googletest is required in at least 3 places (grpc, bloaty, protobuf-master (required by bloaty, but not required by protobuf-3.0.x which is required directly by grpc)).  Where should I set my GTEST_ROOT to point to, and how will that work with a module that expects it to be somewhere under its own third_party branch?  How does one install Googletest after it has been built?

cmake looks for what looks like all (or many of) the standard C #include files.  Many are found, and many are not found (I am building from VS2015 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt, so the applicable LIB and INCLUDE paths should be available; I've looked at them, and they appear reasonable.).  If it searches for all of these by default, then I am guessing that not finding some should not be a problem (if they are not used by grpc or its dependencies), so I haven't chased them down.  However, one that is not found is pthread.h (and I understand at least one module uses pthreads, but the next line of cmake output is "Found Threads: TRUE").  Another disturbing finding is "-- Check size of off64_t - failed" (It seems that such a value could be important for defining protobuf structures.)  CMake also runs many tests.  Some succeed; others don't.  Should I be concerned with the test failures (which ones)?

I've also noticed that many of these modules change [almost] daily, so it occurs to me that dependency on a master version in the GitHub repository could break at any time.  Has anyone built a C++ gRPC for Windows recently?

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Unless you're set on building it on your own, it's a *whole* lot easier to start by downloading and building [vcpkg](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg), then using `vcpkg install grpc` to download and build grpc.

Comment: My operating environment is very restrictive.  Software development is not allowed on computers with internet access, and git and vcpkg are not among the software authorized for use on the connected computers.

Comment: That does make life a lot tougher. Perhaps you could still download vcpkg somewhere, and read through the "recipe" it uses to do the building, and basically do the same things it does?

Comment: have you tried following https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/BUILDING.md instead of downloading the zips and all the dependencies manually? I understand the current process to build from source is not ideal and we are working on simplifying it, but the instructions in BUILDING.md do work. Also, feel free to check out the community-provided vcpkg  or conan packages.

Comment: I can't get to github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/BUILDING.md, but I am generally following the Windows part of the BUILDING.md that I found at https://github.com/grpc/grpc .
What is OPENSSL_NO_ASM?   environment variable?  cmake argument? VS option?

Comment: BUILDING.md specifies git commands that are not available on my internet-connected computer, so I do my best to constrict a grpc source tree by restoring downloaded .zip files (on target that has no internet access).

Comment: vcpkg is not an option for me because it insists using an internet connection (even if run with --no-downloads) before it will build, and my system has no internet connection.

Comment: I have a working procedure now - including building and running C++ HelloWorld on an unconnected Windows system. -- am willing to post if there's a way to attach a file (??).

Comment: Kudos to @JerryCoffin for the vcpkg solution. I am also in a quite restrictive environment, but vcpkg is a Microsoft tool.

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment directly to roger as I'm missing the required karma points, but I was also able to encounter the same issue on Windows 10. This was working in CMAKE 3.14 and then got broken in 3.19 when I was forced to update my Jenkins server for another reason.

When I use the following (networked, not preferred for this answer but preferred for peace of mind), it works reliably; use this if you have network access on your build machine.

```
# Builds gRPC based on GIT checked-out sources
ExternalProject_Add(grpc
  PREFIX grpc
  SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/path/to/grpc"
  CMAKE_CACHE_ARGS
        -DgRPC_INSTALL:BOOL=ON
        -DgRPC_BUILD_TESTS:BOOL=OFF
        -DgRPC_BUILD_GRPC_RUBY_PLUGIN:BOOL=OFF
        -DgRPC_PROTOBUF_PROVIDER:STRING=module
        -DgRPC_PROTOBUF_PACKAGE_TYPE:STRING=CONFIG
        -DgRPC_ZLIB_PROVIDER:STRING=module
        -DgRPC_CARES_PROVIDER:STRING=module
        -DgRPC_SSL_PROVIDER:STRING=module
        -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/grpc
  DEPENDS c-ares protobuf zlib
)
```

If you can't do that, I had to do things the difficulty way by building each component individually, tracking their install location, then adding them as arguments to the ExternalProjectAdd...

```
# Builds c-ares project from the git submodule.
ExternalProject_Add(c-ares
  PREFIX c-ares
  SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/path/to/cares"
  CMAKE_CACHE_ARGS
        -DCARES_SHARED:BOOL=OFF
        -DCARES_STATIC:BOOL=ON
        -DCARES_STATIC_PIC:BOOL=ON
        -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/c-ares
)

# Builds protobuf project from the git submodule.
ExternalProject_Add(protobuf
  PREFIX protobuf
  SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/path/to/protobuf/cmake"
  CMAKE_CACHE_ARGS
        -Dprotobuf_BUILD_TESTS:BOOL=OFF
        -Dprotobuf_WITH_ZLIB:BOOL=OFF
        -Dprotobuf_MSVC_STATIC_RUNTIME:BOOL=OFF
        -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/protobuf
)

# Builds zlib project from the git submodule.
ExternalProject_Add(zlib
  PREFIX zlib
  SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/path/to/zlib"
  CMAKE_CACHE_ARGS
        -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/zlib
)

# the location where protobuf-config.cmake will be installed varies by platform

set(_FINDPACKAGE_PROTOBUF_CONFIG_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/protobuf/cmake")

# if OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR is set, propagate that hint path to the external projects with OpenSSL dependency.
set(_CMAKE_ARGS_OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR "-DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR:PATH=${OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR}")

# Builds gRPC based on locally checked-out sources and set arguments so that all the dependencies
# are correctly located.
ExternalProject_Add(grpc
  PREFIX grpc
  SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/path/to/grpc"
  CMAKE_CACHE_ARGS
        -DgRPC_INSTALL:BOOL=ON
        -DgRPC_BUILD_TESTS:BOOL=OFF
        -DgRPC_BUILD_GRPC_RUBY_PLUGIN:BOOL=OFF
        -DgRPC_PROTOBUF_PROVIDER:STRING=package
        -DgRPC_PROTOBUF_PACKAGE_TYPE:STRING=CONFIG
        -DProtobuf_DIR:PATH=${_FINDPACKAGE_PROTOBUF_CONFIG_DIR}
        -DgRPC_ZLIB_PROVIDER:STRING=package
        -DZLIB_ROOT:STRING=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/zlib
        -DgRPC_CARES_PROVIDER:STRING=module
        -Dc-ares_DIR:PATH=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/c-ares/lib/cmake/c-ares
        -DgRPC_SSL_PROVIDER:STRING=package
        ${_CMAKE_ARGS_OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR}
        -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/grpc
  DEPENDS c-ares protobuf zlib
)
```